# WebViev in React-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

Hi I'm new to this and when I try to download a pdf file from a url it saves it in bin format. I am trying to download from this address
https://portal.bsu.edu.ge/Download.php?Key=m==AO2kjMtYGZw1SMwlGZtUDNzQTL2YDMz0iMzkjNm
please help me

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'; import {   AppRegistry,   StyleSheet,   View,   StatusBar,   BackHandler,   PermissionsAndroid,   Text,   Platform,   Alert,   Linking, // Add the Linking module } from 'react-native'; import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview'; import SplashScreen from './src/SplashScreen'; import NetInfo from '@react-native-community/netinfo'; import RNFetchBlob from 'rn-fetch-blob'; const BsuPortal = () => {   const [showSplashScreen, setShowSplashScreen] = useState(true);   const webViewRef = useRef(null);   const [newUrl, setNewUrl] = useState(''); const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);   const [isConnected, setIsConnected] = useState(true);   useEffect(() => {
    const backAction = () => {
      if (webViewRef.current) {
        webViewRef.current.goBack();
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    };
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', backAction);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setShowSplashScreen(false);
    }, 3000);
    return () => {
      BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', backAction);
    };   }, []);   useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = NetInfo.addEventListener((state) => {
      setIsConnected(state.isConnected);
    });
    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };   }, []);   const requestFileDownloadPermission = async () => {
    try {
      const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
      );
      return granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error requesting file download permission:', error);
      return false;
    }   };   const handleWebViewNavigation = (newNavState) => {
    const { url, navigationType } = newNavState;
    if (!isConnected) {
      // No Internet alert removed
      return false;
    }
    if (navigationType === 'click') {
      if (url.includes('.pdf')) {
        if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
          requestFileDownloadPermission().then((granted) => {
            if (granted) {
              webViewRef.current.stopLoading(); // Stop the web view from navigating to the PDF URL
              handleDownloadConfirmation(url);
              return false;
            } else {
              // Permission Required alert removed
              return false;
            }
          });
        } else {
          // For iOS, you can handle the PDF download here according to your requirements
          // For example, you can open the PDF URL in Safari or a PDF viewer app
          return false;
        }
      } else if (url.startsWith('mailto:')) {
        // Extract the email address from the mailto URL
        const emailAddress = url.split(':')[1];
        // Open the default email app
        const emailURL = `mailto:${emailAddress}`;
        Linking.canOpenURL(emailURL)
          .then((supported) => {
            if (supported) {
              return Linking.openURL(emailURL);
            } else {
              throw new Error('Default email app is not installed.');
            }
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error opening default email app:', error);
          });
        return false;
      } else if (url.includes('mail.google.com')) {
        Linking.openURL(url); // Open in default Gmail app
        return false;
      } else if (url.includes('facebook.com')) {
        Linking.openURL(url); // Open in default Facebook app
        return false;
      } else if (url.includes('instagram.com')) {
        Linking.openURL(url); // Open in default Instagram app
        return false;
      } else if (url.includes('youtube.com')) {
        Linking.openURL(url); // Open in default YouTube app
        return false;
      } else if (url.includes('zoom.us')) {
        Linking.openURL(url); // Open in default Zoom app
        return false;
      } else if (url.includes('teams.microsoft.com')) {
        Linking.openURL(url); // Open in default Microsoft Teams app
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;   };   const downloadFile = async (url) => {
    try {
      const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
      );
  
      if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
        const response = await RNFetchBlob.config({
          fileCache: true,
          addAndroidDownloads: {
            useDownloadManager: true,
            notification: true,
            path: RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.DownloadDir + '/BsuPortal.pdf', // Update the file name here
          },
        }).fetch('GET', url);
  
        console.log('File downloaded:', response.path());
      } else {
        console.log('Download permission denied.');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error downloading file:', error);
    }   };   const handleDownloadConfirmation = (url) => {
    Alert.alert(
      'Download Confirmation',
      'Are you sure you want to download this file?',
      [
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          style: 'cancel',
          onPress: () => {
            // Cancel the download
            webViewRef.current.reload();
          },
        },
        {
          text: 'Download',
          onPress: () => {
            // Download the file using the URL
            if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
              requestFileDownloadPermission().then((granted) => {
                if (granted) {
                  downloadFile(url);
                } else {
                  // Permission Required alert removed
                  webViewRef.current.reload();
                }
              });
            } else {
              // For iOS, you can handle the download here according to your requirements
              // For example, you can use a library like react-native-fs to download the file
              // or open the URL in Safari for direct download
              return false;
            }
          },
        },
      ]
    );   };   return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <StatusBar backgroundColor="#03a9f3" barStyle="dark-content" />
      {showSplashScreen ? (
        <View style={styles.splashContainer}>
          <StatusBar backgroundColor="#ffffff" barStyle="dark-content" />
          <SplashScreen />
        </View>
      ) : (
        <>
          {!isConnected && (
            <View style={styles.internetMessageContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.internetMessageText}>Please turn on the Internet.</Text>
            </View>
          )}
          <WebView
            ref={webViewRef}
            source={{ uri: newUrl || 'https://portal.bsu.edu.ge/' }}
            style={styles.webView}
            onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={handleWebViewNavigation}
            javaScriptEnabled={true}
            onLoadStart={() => setLoading(true)}
            onLoadEnd={() => setLoading(false)}
            onLoad={() => setLoading(false)}
            scrollEnabled={false}
            useWebKit={true} // Use WKWebView engine
            scalesPageToFit={false}
            setSupportMultipleWindows={false}
            injectedJavaScript={`
              const meta = document.createElement('meta');
              meta.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0');
              meta.setAttribute('name', 'viewport');
              document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);
            `}
            onMessage={({ nativeEvent }) => {
              const { type, url } = JSON.parse(nativeEvent.data);
              if (type === 'openNewWindow') {
                webViewRef.current.injectJavaScript(`
                  var newWindow = window.open('${url}', '_blank'); newWindow.opener = null;
                `);
              }
            }}
            allowsInlineMediaPlayback={true} // Enable inline video playback
            allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures={true} // Enable swipe navigation gestures
            allowsLinkPreview={true} // Enable link preview on long press
            allowsPictureInPictureMediaPlayback={true} // Enable picture-in-picture video playback
            allowsFullscreenVideo={true} // Enable fullscreen video playback
            onDownloadStart={({ nativeEvent }) => {
              // Download the file when the user clicks on a download link
              handleDownloadConfirmation(nativeEvent.url);
            }}
          />
        </>
      )}
    </View>   ); }; const styles = StyleSheet.create({   container: {
    flex: 1,   },   splashContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#000000',   },   webView: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',   },   internetMessageContainer: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)',   },   internetMessageText: {
    color: '#000000',
    fontSize: 18,   }, }); AppRegistry.registerComponent('BsuPortal', () => BsuPortal); export default BsuPortal;
```

**I'm testing this app on an Android device and I also have another problem where the Mail app doesn't redirect me to the default Gmail app.**